# Is that advisable to use 20 sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web application requires various values to be used across different pages. Will that 20 sessions degrade the performance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer clearly depends on the memory you have. To keep it simple the way it is taken is as:

```
Number-of-concurrent-Users * Size-Of-Session < Available-Memory
```

So if the available memory you have is more than yes you can use that and there is no harm in doing that. However if the available memory is less than it is not advisable as that may lead you to some memory issues and some abrupt behavior.

Comment: In case of low memory. What would be the best alternative?

Comment: @Shaharyar:- In that case it would be better to set the maximum limit of the session and allow only that number of sessions!(*Although I am not sure if you are looking for this*)

Comment: My question was, how will I use some information across the pages without keeping them in session?

Comment: @Shaharyar:- There are many ways for that like you can use query string etc. Check this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What about `static` objects or variables? I think they will also be stored in the server memory?